# R equivalent to Matlab re-ordering of Schur factorization?

Tags: r, matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

Is there an equivalent to the MATLAB function ordschur (documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ordschur.html)) in R?

The function re-orders the Schur factorization X = U*T*U' produced by the schur function and returns the reordered Schur matrix TS and the cumulative orthogonal transformation US such that X = US*TS*US'. I am particularly interested in the 'lhp' method - also described in the MATLAB documentation link.

Note that there is a function Schur in the package Matrix (see CRAN documentation [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matrix/Matrix.pdf) ) R which performs the Schur decomposition and eigenvalues of a square matrix. Update: This function also returns the Unitary orthogonal matrix U.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know MATLAB uses `?TRSEN` function from LAPACK to perform reordering. You can look at some limited implementation [here](https://www.dynare.org/trac/browser/mex/sources/ordschur/ordschur.cc?rev=80b5c23346bc9875c520e8b13dfe53f8d3be8c49). In order to bring this functionality into R you can implement this routine by yourself.